# Text Templates - Open Graph Aggregations - Operator with Formatter

Tags: text, facebook-opengraph

Facebook provides the ability to use text formatters to format Open Graph data.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/template/

Therefore you can use: {my_duration | duration} to display a time. You can also use operator's  in aggregations, e.g. {my_duration | sum} which gives the total number of seconds.

How do you apply both an operator and a formatter? I've tried {my_duration | sum | duration} but this simply returns 0:00.